# dequeue implementation in Queue class from book 'Data Structure and algorithms in python' by M. Goodrich

Tags: python, queue

I am studying book 'Data Structure and algorithms in python' by M. Goodrich and was looking dequeue implementation in queue class, please see below:

```py
    class Queue:
      DEFAULT_CAPACITY = 10
      def __init__(self):        
        self._data = [None] * Queue.DEFAULT_CAPACITY
        self._size = 0  # queue current size
        self._front = 0

      def __len__(self):
        return self._size

      def is_empty(self):
        return self._size == 0

      def enqueue(self, dt):
        if self._size == len(self._data):
            self._resize(2 * len(self._data)) 
        empty = (self._front + self._size) % len(self._data)
        self._data[empty] = dt
        self._size += 1

      def first(self):
        if self.is_empty():
            raise QueueisEmpty
        return self._data[self._front]

      def dequeue(self):
        if self.is_empty():
            raise QueueisEmpty("Queue is empty")
        answer = self._data[self._front]
        self._data[self._front] = None
        self._front = (self._front + 1) % len(self._data)
        self._size -= 1
        return ret

      def _resize(self, desired_size):
        old = self._data
        walk = self._front
        self._data = [None] * desired_size
        for i in range(self._size):
            self._data[i] = old[walk]
            walk = (1 + walk) % len(old)
        self._front = 0

    class QueueisEmpty(BaseException):
        pass
```

if you look dequeue method you will see that it checks that queue is not empty then get a reference to the first element by

> answer = self._data[self._front]

I am curious why the author is not used built-in self.first() method instead.
This way it will have two benefits in my opinion:

1. it will have a shorter code
2. it will take care of empty queue cases

Comment: I mean, that sounds like a question *for the author*. But to me it looks like not encapsulated code.

Comment: yes, but as a programmer I want to hear your opinions what is the reason doing this way...  also what do you mean by not encapsulated code?

Comment: There is no good reason, it looks like *bad code*. Again, this question isn't really appropriate for stack overflow.  In any case, of your reasons, having shorter code is never really a great reason, and as for point 2, the authors code *does that already*, however, now it is doing it in two separate places.. The point is, you should encapsulate code that you intend to re-use, like in say, that method, and then when you need that functionality re-use the method. You *should* do that. Why the author *didn't* do that, I can't say. You should ask the author. Likely, it is just an oversight.